# Make Current Line in Read-Only Rich Text Box Editable

Tags: c#, forms, richtextbox

I'm attempting to make a command prompt clone in C# so I can get familiar with using IO. However, instead of just one text body, I created two text boxes (one for the command and another for the "parameters") and a rich text box to view the result of the commands. It may sound confusing and the title may be misleading, but I didn't know how else to word it. Anyway, my question is- how do you make *only* the current line editable and the rest read-only? And how would I be able to combine the commands and parameters in the two text boxes so I wouldn't need *two* separate text boxes? I have spent 6 days trying to figure out the logic to implement this but I got nothing.

**Here's a picture of the form:**

[image]

**And here's what I want to make it similar to:**

[image]

Comment: You should check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425847/current-line-and-column-numbers-in-a-richtextbox-in-a-winforms-application and find if current column is greater than first > in the line...

Comment: Thanks. I've created a new Windows Forms project to test this out. Now, I'll try to apply this to my program.

Comment: Have you considered using `ListBox` instead?

Comment: @Dinah, unfortunately, I didn't consider using ListBox. But I already fixed the "make the current line editable" problem. Thanks for the suggestion, tough. I'll consider it for similar projects.

Comment: Now that I think of it, It would of been much easier to make a console application instead of a Windows Forms application... Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do that, but if it was me, and this was a "get it done now" situation (and this is just off the top of my head), I would create a user control to contain the "screen". This user control would have the RTF or list box as the top, and a textbox flush under it.

I would remove the borders and wrap both these controls in a panel that has borders. This would simulate a single control.

The textbox would check for the enter key in one of the key-press events, and the control itself would have events that could be handled by the parent control.

This may be hacky, but it would probably be what I'd do in a last minute situation.

Oh as far as the command and parameter stuff, if you read the textbox as a single value, then split the string into an List or array, you could then define a switch or some other conditional code that would know what to do with parameters (index 1+), based on the value of the first item/index.