# VB.NET - richtextbox - counter on the left side

Tags: counter

I am probably the first one to ask this question. How do I add a counter on the left side of a richtextbox form like this?

1.
2.
3.
and so forth.
I haven't found a single answer. I appreciate all help! Have a nice day!

`[Visual Basic 2010 Express]`

Here is an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/FastColoredTextBox_/fastcoloredtextbox2.png

Comment: No, you're not :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657635/displaying-line-number-in-rich-text-box-c-sharp - lots of useful information here.